# Dynamic textboxes error Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Tags: c#, xml, dynamic, xmlwriter

Hello there im trying to save some data from dynamic textboxes into XML file. But everytime i try i get this error

"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
                document.Load(@"myGrades.xml");            
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                {
                    **TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)textboxComputer[i];** //<- error is thrown here
                    string markGained = tb1.Text;
                    this.Text = markGained;
                    XmlElement root = document.DocumentElement;
                    XmlElement newAssessmentMark = document.CreateElement("Assessment");
                    XmlElement newMark = document.CreateElement("AssessmentMark");
                    XmlText mark = document.CreateTextNode(markGained);
                    newAssessmentMark.AppendChild(newMark);
                    newMark.AppendChild(mark);
                    XmlNode parentNode = document.SelectSingleNode("myGrades/courseStructure/level4");
                    parentNode.InsertAfter(newAssessmentMark, parentNode.LastChild);

                    document.Save(@"myGrades.xml");

                }

                this.Close();
```

Help appreciated :)

Comment: Well how big is `textboxComputer`? Please show us the code that initializes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`textboxComputer` seems to be an array, so in your for loop do:

`for( int i = 0; i < textboxComputer.Length; i++ ) ...`

Alternatively you can pre-compute it:

`int length = textboxComputer.Length;`

`for( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) ...`